# Entity relationship dubts

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Two tables Utenti and Nuclei related each other

Utenti SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.utentiweb
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    username character varying(200),
    password character varying(128),
    idnucleo bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
)
```

Nuclei SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.datinuclei
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    idcomune integer NOT NULL,
    cognome character varying,
    nome character varying,
)
```

Utenti

```
/**
 * Utentiweb
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utentiweb")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Utenti implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="utentiweb_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Nuclei
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Nuclei", mappedBy="utente")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idnucleo", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $nucleo;
```

Nuclei

```
/**
 * Nuclei
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="datinuclei")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\NucleiRepository")
 */
class Nuclei
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Utenti
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Utenti", inversedBy="nucleo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $utente;
```

**Getting Nucleo from Utente WORKS**

```
    $utente = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Utenti::class)->find(3078);
    dump($utente->getNucleo()->getNome());
```

**Getting Utente from Nucleo DOESN'T WORK**

```
    $nucleo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Nuclei::class)->find(5780);
    dump($nucleo->getUtente()->getUsername());
```

**Error:**

```
    Entity of type 'App\Entity\Utenti' for IDs id(5780) was not found
```

There is something wrong on Nuclei relationship annotation but i don't know how to solve, nuclei.id should be related to utenti.idnucleo. Tried many combination without success

thanks

**UPDATE JoinColumn remove on Nuclei entity**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, 
t0.tiponucleo AS tiponucleo_2, t0.codicenucleo AS codicenucleo_3, 
t0.nome AS nome_4, t0.cognome AS cognome_5, t0.codicefiscale AS 
codicefiscale_6, t0.ncomponenti AS ncomponenti_7, t0.indirizzo AS 
indirizzo_8, t0.indirizzoutenza AS indirizzoutenza_9, t0.civico AS 
civico_10, t0.mail AS mail_11, t0.telefono AS telefono_12, 
t0.cellulare AS cellulare_13, t0.utente_id AS utente_id_14, 
t0.idcomune AS idcomune_15 FROM datinuclei t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with 
params [5780]:

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.utente_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ono AS telefono_12, t0.cellulare AS cellulare_13, t0.utente_...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

From class `Nuclei` field `$utent`

Comment: JoinColumn removed but throw an sql error... it use a columns "t0.utente_id" wich does not exist..

Comment: And flip `mappedBy` with `inversedBy`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Leprechaunz/36f0207f10a3427500249d978bb744a9
https://gist.github.com/Leprechaunz/298cd8e9764be9fbd6265ec540c2d62d

Comment: Applied, i get an infinite loading.. maybe because there are about 13k Utenti?
I has to restart the local webserver :/

Comment: Looking webserver log i recive thound of this lines [Application    ] Jun 23 17:58:47 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.usertype AS usertype_4, t0.attivato AS attivato_5, t0.ultimoaccesso AS ultimoaccesso_6, t0.idnucleo AS idnucleo_7, t0.idcomune AS idcomune_8 FROM utentiweb t0 WHERE t0.idnucleo = ? 0=14301

it seems works but load all entities!!

Comment: Which query returns all entities?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216511/discussion-between-augusto-murri-and-leprechaun).

Comment: thanks you problem solved, i don't know how to accept your answer sorry